# Tortoise SVN with multiple developers approach

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a team of 20 developers constantly working on an MVC5 application. I am using tortoise SVN to combine the works of all the users into a single application.

Should I create individual branches for the developers so they can work individually and at the end I can merge in?
But this would create a lot of overhead and doesn't seem to be optimum as well.

What is the best approach so that i can get minimum conflicts and optimum results?

Answer (score 2):

You will **always** get conflicts, the real trick is in how you manage those conflicts. And "optimum results" is a rather subjective measure, don't you think?

First, let's discuss how you're currently working. It sounds like you're the only person managing the source control, and all changes flow through you. This is not going to well for you and will in fact cause more conflicts than necessary. Each user should be responsible for his own commits to a central (in the case of Subversion) repository, and should commit anytime he has a change that is complete - this can be a single method, a refactoring of a whole class, whatever you want - as long as it's not completely broken.

This means you need a centralized server which **all** users check out from and check into. Each user gets his own set of credentials. That repository is considered the canonical, definitive source code - if it's not in there, it doesn't exist.

Once that's set up, you can choose a few modes of working:

1. Shared trunk (everyone points to the same source code & commits against the same URL)
2. Developer private branches
3. A mixture of the above (for experimental/long-running, breaking changes)

The trouble you'll run into with approach #2 is you'll have to merge. **A lot**. This will generate a lot of conflicts - not only do each developers' changes have to get merged to the trunk (definitive, common source from which you build), each developer will need to merge the latest trunk into their branch (or from other developers' branches).

With approach #1, you'll still get conflicts, but if you're updating working copies and committing changes back to the repository regularly, they'll be smaller & much easier to manage.

Remember that at its core, any VCS is a **communication tool**. The more isolated you keep each developer's thought process from everyone else's (private branches), the harder it will be to bring their ideas back together. And it is only one tool in your team's toolset - nothing will replace actually talking to one another about who is doing what.

Finally, you really need to read the [Subversion Manual](http://svnbook.org/) as it explains how it's meant to be used. The section ["To Branch or not to Branch"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.when.html) will be especially helpful, but really, you ought to read the whole book. It'll take an afternoon or so.

Comment: I have same I have same situation as described above in question, this issue can be solved by using Git i believe, but is there any solution with your approach #2 as that is what I want with Tortoise svn